# sh: 1: tailwind: not found when deploying to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, tailwind-css

`package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^0.7.4"
  },
"scripts": {
    "tailwind:css": "tailwind build src/css/tailwind.src.css -c tailwind.js -o src/css/tailwind.css",
    "start": "npm run tailwind:css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run tailwind:css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

error:

```
sh: 1: tailwind: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 tailwind:css: `tailwind build src/css/tailwind.src.css -c tailwind.js -o src/css/tailwind.css`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 tailwind:css script.
```

Comment: If heroku is building your app with NODE_ENV=production then it won't install devDependencies

Answer (score 1):

Even though (in my experience) some heroku deployments seem to somehow get away with tailwind in the devDependencies, moving it into your `dependencies` does fix this issue.

This can affect more than just tailwind, so you might need to move more than just tailwind across for your build to work.